# Spree Commerce error on checkout: "We are unable to ship the selected items to your shipping address."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'd love to have help troubleshooting a frustrating issue I'm having. Setting up Spree for the first time, but I've been developing in Rails for 3 years so I'm familiar with how it works.

Pretty much default set-up.  But when I try to check out, clicking "Save and Continue" on the Address page, I get the error in the title.  I can see from the order model where the error is coming from: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-0-stable/core/app/models/spree/order.rb

```
def ensure_available_shipping_rates
  if shipments.empty? || shipments.any? { |shipment| shipment.shipping_rates.blank? }
    errors.add(:base, Spree.t(:items_cannot_be_shipped)) and return false
  end
end
```

Haven't easily been able to figure out which of those conditions are returning true. If it was my app, I would just add a debugger statement and check things out that way.  Can anyone give me any advice on how to troubleshoot further or what to try.

I'm on Rails 3.2.14, Spree 2-0-stable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There's a few ways you can go about this.  If you want to add debug statements, you can open up the gem:

```
bundle show spree_core
```

edit the code, restart your rails server, and debug as you normally would.  Don't forget to change it back!

If you want to be a bit less invasive, you can fire up a rails console.  Grab the order you're working with (probably Spree::Order.last) and figure out what's happening.

You're probably running in to an issue with shipping methods and zones.  A Spree::Zone lists a set of countries (for example, US, Canada, and Mexico could define your North America zone).  Spree::ShippingMethod defines how much it costs to ship something to a particular zone.  These settings can all be defined in the admin interface.

You've likely selected a country that is either not in a defined zone, or is in a defined zone which has no shipping methods.  Spree doesn't know how much it costs to ship the item (or if it's available to be shipped there), so it triggers the error which you are seeing.

Hope that helps.  Good luck getting Spree up and going!

Comment: I didn't know about this `bundle show` command, thanks a million @gmacdougall !

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting a new app from scratch (since I wasn't too far into things) and it's working fine now. I remember I had gotten an error when adding the sample data, which I thought I had resolved, but maybe that was behind it.